Recyclerview is not shown
I want to put row_center_list.xml in the recyclerView called gym_list_recycler of fragment_center. I don't know because gpt says there are no code errors. I folloed every steps that ChatGPT told. Making an adatper, create Item xml ,,
I have no idea about why recyclerview is not shown. it' s my first time posting my question, so please explain me kindly...
<!-----------CenterFragment.kt-------------!>

class CenterFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var fragmentCenterBinding: FragmentCenterBinding
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        view?.let { super.onViewCreated(it, savedInstanceState) }

        val centers = listOf(
            Center("Fit Center", "Best gym in town / 5 stars / Free water", "Crossfit", "1234 Street, 2km", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            Center("Health Club", "New classes available / 4.5 stars / Free towel", "Yoga", "5678 Avenue, 500m", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        )

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_center, container, false)

        val purpleColor = Color.parseColor("#800080") // 보라색 정수 값
        val defaultColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT) // 투명 색상을 나타내는 ColorStateList 생성


        val chipDistance = view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chip_distance)
        val chipDailyPass = view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chip_daily_pass)
        val chipDiscount = view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chip_discount)

        val chipClickListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val chip = v as Chip
            // 현재 칩 색상 확인 후 색상 변경
            if (chip.chipBackgroundColor?.defaultColor != purpleColor) {
                chip.chipBackgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(purpleColor)
            } else {
                chip.chipBackgroundColor = defaultColor
            }
        }

        chipDistance.setOnClickListener(chipClickListener)
        chipDailyPass.setOnClickListener(chipClickListener)
        chipDiscount.setOnClickListener(chipClickListener)



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_center, container, false)
    }

    class CenterAdapter(private val centerList: List<Center>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CenterAdapter.CenterViewHolder>() {

        class CenterViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCenterPicture)
            val buttonLike: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLikeOff)
            val textViewNotice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNotice)
            val textViewCategory: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory)
            val textViewCenterName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCenterName)
            val textViewDistance: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDistance)
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CenterViewHolder {
            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_center_list, parent, false)
            return CenterViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CenterViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val currentCenter = centerList[position]
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentCenter.imageResourceId)
            holder.textViewNotice.text = currentCenter.notice
            holder.textViewCategory.text = currentCenter.category
            holder.textViewCenterName.text = currentCenter.name
            holder.textViewDistance.text = currentCenter.address


            holder.buttonLike.setOnClickListener {

            }
        }
        override fun getItemCount() = centerList.size
    }
    data class Center(
        val name: String,
        val notice: String,
        val category: String,
        val address: String,
        val imageResourceId: Int
    )
}

<!-------------row_center_list.xml-------------!>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="143dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterPicture"
                android:layout_width="123dp"
                android:layout_height="103dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.355"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="222dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLikeOff"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:onClick="onImageClick"
                app:icon="@drawable/favorite"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.181" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNotice"
                android:layout_width="381dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:text="공지사항 / 후기 점수 / 무료 서비스"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="12dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="운동 종류"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="197dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCenterName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="센터 이름"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewCategory"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="197dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="주소, 거리"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewCenterName"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="197dp" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</layout>

<!------------------------fragment_center.xml----------------------!>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="운동 센터"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/trainerInfoTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
                app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="헬스" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="필라테스" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="수영" />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:singleLine="true">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip_distance"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:onClick="onSortByDistanceClicked"
                    android:text="거리순"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/InputCompartmentOutline_Color" />


                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip_daily_pass"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:text="일일권"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/InputCompartmentOutline_Color" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip_discount"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:text="할인시설"
                    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/InputCompartmentOutline_Color" />

            </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Detail_Padding"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/gym_list_recylcler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</layout>


it looks like u haven't written .setAdapter()
to be honest i am new in this field so it as a pinch of salt
i hope this helps

You are not affiliating your recyclerView with the CenterAdapter because of that it is not populated at all and that’s why not displayed.
You need to call:
recyclerView.setAdapter(CenterAdapter(centers))


First, you need to connect recyclerView with XML:
recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.gym_list_recylcler)

After that set Adapter to the recyclerView:
recyclerView.setAdapter(CenterAdapter(centers))

